# What is the difference between "IS NOT NULL" and "NOT IN NULL"? Why these two Oracle queries return different results?

Tags: oracle

1. SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL 
     WHERE DUMMY IS NOT NULL;

   Result: Returns 'X';
2. SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL 
     WHERE DUMMY NOT IN NULL;

   Result: Returns nothing.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-how-nulls-affect-in-and-exists/

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle binary expressions can evaluate to three states: `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL` where `NULL` can be thought of as the same as a undefined or unknown value. Applying a binary operation to a `NULL` value will give a `NULL` output (and not, as you might expect, `TRUE` or `FALSE`):

```
Boolean Operation Result
----------------- ------
X = X             TRUE
X = Y             FALSE
X = NULL          NULL
NULL = X          NULL
NULL = NULL       NULL
NULL IN ( NULL )  NULL
NOT TRUE          FALSE
NOT FALSE         TRUE
NOT NULL          NULL
```

The query:

```
SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY NOT IN ( NULL )
```

is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL WHERE NOT( DUMMY = NULL )
```

And the `WHERE` clause evaluates `NOT( DUMMY = NULL )` to `NOT NULL` which in turn evaluates to `NULL`. Since the `WHERE` filter evaluates to a non-`TRUE` value the row is excluded.

The `IS NULL` operation is specifically designed to test whether a value is `NULL` and will do what you intend where the equality `=` operator or `IN` operator will not.

So:

```
Boolean Operation Result
----------------- ------
NULL = NULL       NULL
NULL IN ( NULL )  NULL
NULL IS NULL      TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

1. DUMMY in DUAL is a varchar2, and you selected all DUMMY from DUAL that are not null (IS NOT NULL).  DUAL has one row with DUMMY='X'.
2. Now you are saying that DUMMY is not IN a set of NULL, which makes no sense really and the select will return no result.

NULL is a special character, and is not zero.  It represents the absence of real data (data which includes zeroes and empty spaces).